# How to execute mongoexport command using a java program

Tags: java, mongodb

Team,

I'm in need of exporting Collection from mongodb using a standalone Java Program. Can anyone help me in doing so?

Thanks

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I have tried some few lines of code. 

String expCommand = "mongoexport --d "+database+" --out "+exportPath+" --collection "+collection;
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(expCommand);

Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you just use wrong arguments?
Try

```
String expCommand1 = "mongoexport --db "+database+" --out "+exportPath+" --collection "+collection;
String expCommand2 = "mongoexport -d "+database+" --out "+exportPath+" --collection "+collection;
```